# Applescript to cause iTunes to play an album by Apple Music URL?

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, itunes

I'm attempting to script iTunes to play an arbitrary playlist or an arbitrary album from a shell script.

I've solved the playlist problem with the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to open location "'$url'?cmd=AddStation"'
```

Where url is an itmss:// type URL to a playlist. Without the "cmd=AddStation" parameter, it won't automatically play.

This doesn't work for an album URL, however. If I execute:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to open location "'$url'"'
```

where url is defined as an itmss:// album URL, then the album does come up on iTunes, but it won't start playing. If I tell iTunes to play via Applescript, it instead starts playing the first album in the entire iTunes library, not the album that is displayed.

There was a similar question about a year back here [Applescript play music from iTunes URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647648/applescript-play-music-from-itunes-url) ; however, the solution provided in that response requires you to know the title of the first track you want to play. Does anyone have an idea for a more generic solution that will bring an album from the command-line and then play the first track?

Comment: What is the result returned by running `osascript -s s -e 'tell app "iTunes" to return the name of every subscription playlist"` ?

Comment: That returns a list of Apple playlists I have added to my Apple Music collection in the past, but doesn't seem to have anything to do with whatever is currently being played. It looks like:

{"'80s Hits for the Whole Family", "'80s Soft Rock Essentials", "<80><99>60s Hits Essentials", "<80><99>90s Indie Essentials", ....}

Comment: I don't use Apple Music, so I'm possibly not understanding how the service operates, but one thought I had was that either your subscription playlists would contain the any album you had permission to open with its URL; or, if not, that you use AppleScript to make a new subscription playlist that contains the URL tracks to each song in the album, which you could then play. In AppleScript, iTunes's albums are actually just playlists, and these can contain URL streams and be played on command.

Comment: `/Applications/Reminders.app/Contents/Resources/*.sdef` just matches `Reminders.sdef`, which is a wholly generic file that has nothing to do with this iTunes issue. How is it relevant to the question?

The "subscriptions" playlist just returns the name of every Apple-provided playlists I've added to my collection. If I request "every playlist" (instead of "every subscription playlist") I also get my own custom playlist in my collection. But neither returns radio stations I've created or attempted to play, or individual albums.

Comment: `osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to open location "'$url'"'` does open the Album corresponding to $url in iTunes, but it doesn't start it playing. There does not appear to be a consistent, graceful way to cause iTunes to start playing whatever resource has been loaded up via the `open location` command. If you just tell iTunes to start playing, it will play the first track in the entire collection, not what is on the screen. It seems like the only solution here may be a screen-scraping script, but I don't see an easy consistent way to do that either.

Comment: My apologies.  I left that comment on completely the wrong page.  Eek!

Comment: This appears to be work on Catalina/Music App, although obviously it's quite fragile:
`tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Music"

        click button 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1

    end tell

end tell`